# Program to find the product of odd numbers from 1 to n and the sum of the squares of even numbers according to the number n entered from the keyboard

Tags: c#, console

I'm new to the programming world and I'm learning C#. I have an algorithm given to me in expression language and I need to do it with C# .NET Framework console application, but I'm not very good at it. Can you help?

Here's the algorithm I'm talking about;

1. Start
2. int toplam, carpım, karetoplam
3. toplam=0
4. carpım=1
5. Read N

6.Cycle I=1, N, 1

7. if(N%2==1)
8. toplam=toplam+I
9. carpım=carpım*I
10. else
11. karetoplam=karetoplam+(I*I)
12. if over
13. cycle over
14. Cw toplam
15. Cw carpım
16. Cw karetoplam
17. Done

Answer (score 1):

I only understood the title of your post not the text ;)
Code is untested. Could be optimized to 1 for-loop in  1 method.

Product of oddnumber from 1 to n?

```
long GetProductsOfOddNumbers(int n) {
   var product = 1L;
   for (var i = 1; i <= n; i++)  {
       if (i % 2 == 0) continue;
       product *= i;
    }
    return product;
}
```

Sum of squares of even numbers from 1 to n?

```
long GetSumOfSquaresOfEvenNumbers(int n) {
   var sum = 0L;
   for (var i = 1; i <= n; i++)  {
       if (i % 2 != 0) continue;
       sum += (i * i);
    }
    return sum ;
}
```